# Telegraf http listener v2: unable to send JSON with string values

Tags: influxdb, httplistener, telegraf

I'm trying to send this very simple JSON string to Telegraf to be saved into InfluxDB:

```
{ "id": "id_123", "value": 10 }
```

So the request would be this: `curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8080/telegraf' --data-binary '{"id": "id_123","value": 10}'`

When I make that request, I get the following answer: `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content Date: Tue, 20 Apr 2021 13:02:49 GMT` but when I check what was written to database, there is only value field:

```
select * from http_listener_v2

time                host        influxdb_database value
----                ----        ----------------- -----
1618923747863479914 my.host.com my_db             10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my Telegraf config:

```
[global_tags]

[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false

# OUTPUTS

[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  database = "telegraf"
  username = "xxx"
  password = "xxx"
  [outputs.influxdb.tagdrop]
    influxdb_database = ["*"]
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  database = "httplistener"
  username = "xxx"
  password = "xxx"
  [outputs.influxdb.tagpass]
    influxdb_database = ["httplistener"]

# INPUTS

## system
[[inputs.cpu]]  
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]
[[inputs.mem]]
[[inputs.swap]]
[[inputs.system]]

## http listener
[[inputs.http_listener_v2]]
  service_address = ":8080"
  path = "/telegraf"
  methods = ["POST", "PUT"]
  data_source = "body"
  data_format = "json"
  [inputs.http_listener_v2.tags]
    influxdb_database = "httplistener"
```

Comment: Can you share your telegraf config?

Comment: @mhall119 Yes, I added it to original question

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am getting the same very strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use json_string_fields = ["id"]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.